# Jquery not refreshing data on the page?

Tags: php, jquery

This script has been working fine until mid last week where it randomly no longer wanted to live search correctly. That was fixed however now it does not refresh the data on the page, i.e once a match has been made & selected to match before it would then remove these from the page. Now the database is updated however the page remains showing all data & check boxes selected etc.

the ajax/jquery for this part is the following:

```
function createCourse(els)
        {
            els.autocomplete("updateSearch.php", 
            {
                width: 260,
                matchContains: true,
                mustMatch: true,
                selectFirst: false
            });

            els.result(function(event, data, formatted){
                $(this).next(".course_val").val(data[1])
            });
        };
    function title_match_all()
        {
            var intRegex = /^\d+$/;
            $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function ()
            {
                if(this.checked)
                    {
                        if(intRegex.test(this.value))
                            {
                                var info = {};
                                info['url_id']  = this.value;
                                info['product_id'] =$('#match_all').val();

                                $.ajax(
                                        {
                                            type : "POST",
                                            url : "pop.php",
                                            data : info,
                                            success : function(msg) 
                                                    {
                                                        if(msg =='YES')
                                                            {
                                                                 $('#'+info['url_id']).empty(); 
                                                            }
                                                        else
                                                            {
                                                                alert(msg);
                                                            }
                                                    }
                                        }
                                    )
                            }
                    }
            }); 
        }
```

Then pop.php is the following:

```
    $query = "SELECT mainid from Connector WHERE hid=".$_POST['url_id']." AND pid= ".$_POST['product_id'];  
  $id = grab_one_result($query);
if($id[0])
    {

    }
else
    {
        execute_query("INSERT INTO `Connector`(`mainid`, `hid`, `pid`) VALUES ('',".$_POST['url_id'].",".$_POST['product_id'].")");
    }
echo "YES";
?>
```

Previously the if `msg == 'YES'` part worked fine, does anyone have any ideas why all of a sudden it has 'decided' to no longer work? Or of a method to get something like this working again, it's been a long time since I coded this or used `ajax / jquery` so am a bit stumped right now why it'd suddenly die.

Comment: Cache problem maybe? When doing AJAX thingies, it's helpful to always set an expires header...

Comment: Thanks, I've tried adding an expire within my PHP code (further on from th ajax/jquery) however it warns me that they have already been sent on the line I've added them & the page does not refresh still :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To refresh the page, you can use below code,

```
success: function() 
{
  window.location.reload(true);
}
```

This would help to refresh the page.